# How do you add a managed policy to a group in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I've got this so far:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "config_role" { 
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service_role/AWSConfigRole"
}
```

But I'm not sure how to attach this to a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either the [`aws_iam_group_policy_attachment` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_group_policy_attachment.html) or the [`aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html) to attach a policy to a group.

As mentioned in the `aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource docs this resource creates an exclusive attachment of that policy to specified users, groups and roles and isn't normally what you want so I'd recommend the `aws_iam_group_policy_attachment` resource.

This might look something like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "aws_config_group" {
  name = "AWSConfigGroup"
  path = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "aws_config_attach" {
  group      = "${aws_iam_group.aws_config_group.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service_role/AWSConfigRole"
}
```

Note that you don't actually need the [`aws_iam_policy` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy.html) here as you are already building the ARN to pass into the data source and that's all that's needed by the `aws_iam_group_policy_attachment` resource.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To show that an answer solved your problem we don't normally comment on the answer to say thank you but instead [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer instead by ticking the green checkmark to the side of the answer. This shows other people who have the same problem as you that it was a helpful answer. If at any point another answer comes along that solves your original question in a better way then you can always move the acceptance to that new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You add it later down in the file.

so something like

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "aws_config_group" {
  name = "AWSConfigGroup"
  path = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "config_role" {
  name = "AWSConfigRole" 
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service_role/AWSConfigRole"
  group = ['aws_config_group']
}
```

Comment: This isn't a valid use of the `aws_iam_policy` resource. This resource creates the IAM policy and doesn't handle attaching to a group. It's also not what you want when trying to use a service linked role. Also the resource doesn't support the `arn` or `group` parameters.